# Why a ( ) instead of [ ] when deleting hashes?

Tags: ruby

Complete programming beginner just trying to clarify something, I was creating keys for a hash and decided I wanted to delete one. Here were my guesses:

```
hash["key"].­delete
hash.dele­te["key"]
```

I eventually looked it up and I'm suppose to use `( )`:

```
hash.dele­te("key")
```

Since I used a `[ ]` to create the hash, why wouldn't I use it to delete a key? Also, and why wouldn't `hash("key").delete` work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`[]` is actually a method of `Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D), and is treated specially in the language so the parameter goes between the `[]`. It's equivalent to [`store`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-store), which uses standard method syntax.

Likewise, [`delete` is also a method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete), which takes one argument. Doing `hash.delete['foo']` is trying to call `delete` (with no arguments), and then call `[]` on whatever it returns. Doing `hash['foo'].delete` is calling `delete` on whatever is stored in `hash['foo']`.

Comment: BTW: `hsh[:key]` is the same as `hsh.[](:key)`, likewise `hsh[:key] = 42` is the same as `hsh.[]=(:key, 42)`. Try it!

Comment: @JörgWMittag I honestly would've expected that to work but never bothered to try—syntactic sugar is too awesome `:P`. Good to note this though, Ruby has a lot of syntactic special cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

hash.delete() is a method, where hash[] is a sugar syntax (but still a method). You can use hash.store(key, value) if you prefer consistency.

```
hash[:key] = :value
hash.store(:key, :value)
hash.delete(:key)
```